# Подсчитать количество строк идущих ниже выделенных

Tags: excel

В excel таблице есть строки с содержимым "Группа". Нужно подсчитать количество строк идущих после "Группа" до следующей "Группы". Пример того, что должно получиться на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример: диапазон строк 2:26 (25 строк), слова *группа* в столбце `A`, подсчет в столбце `D`.

Чтобы не усложнять получение результата вычислением последнего диапазона (у последней группы нет внизу ограничительного слова), запишем в ячейку ниже диапазона (`А27`) слово *группа*.

В `D2` формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2="группа";МИН(ЕСЛИ(A3:$A$27=A2;СТРОКА(A3:$A$27)-1))-СТРОКА(A2);0)
```

Формула массива, завершить ввод с помощью трех клавиш - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками. Протянуть формулу до строки 26.

---

Для второго варианта слово ограничительное не нужно, но ссылку на ячейку ниже диапазона (`A27`) оставляем, иначе в последней ячейке с формулой будет ошибка (*примечание: если в последней ячейке диапазона гарантированно не будет слова группа, то ссылаться можно на `A26` и не писать формулу в последнюю ячейку* (`D26`))

В `D2` формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2="группа";СТРОКА($26:$26)-СТРОКА(2:2)-СУММ(D3:$D$27)-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A3:$A$27;A2);0)
```

Записанная формула покажет неправильный результат. Это нормально :) Дело в том, что формула учитывает суммы, полученные ниже, а их-то пока что нет. Правильные значения появятся просле протягивания формулы.

Обе показанные формулы в строках без слова *группа* покажут 0 (ноль). Нулевые зеначения можно скрыть (в параметрах листа есть соответствующая галка) или в конце формул вместо нуля вписать пустую строку:

```
...;"")
```

(*примечание: если столбец `D` задействован в дальнейших вычислениях, текст нулевой длины может мешать расчетам*)

Comment: В первом примере в первой группе показывает правильный результат (24), во второй группе -1, потом 0. Во втором примере в первой группе тоже правильно (24), во второй опять 24 и т.д. уже не правильно. Правильно показывает только в первой группе в обоих примерах.

Comment: Неправильные пчелы носят неправильный мед :) Проверил, у меня обе работают нормально. Покажите ссылку на файл, посмотрим.

Comment: [Ссылка на файл](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3zuL/3pk6QAXje)

Comment: Внимательно нужно читать текст ответа. Я специально подробно расписывал о последних ячейках диапазона и о размещении формулы. В столбце `D` Вы не увеличили диапазон, надо: `=ЕСЛИ(A2="группа";МИН(ЕСЛИ(A3:$A$35=A2;СТРОКА(A3:$A$35)-1))-СТРОКА(A2);0)`. Вторую формулу Вы разместили в столбце `F`, но в формуле осталась ссылка на столбец `D`. И нижнюю границу диапазона не изменили. Надо: `=ЕСЛИ(A2="группа";СТРОКА($35:$35)-СТРОКА(2:2)-СУММ(F3:$F$36)-СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A3:$A$36;A2);0)`

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!

Comment: vikttur, спасибо! очень помогло в аналогичной задаче для Google Sheets!